# MockingKernel and Received throws an NotASubstituteException

Tags: ninject

I'm using `NSubstituteMockingKernel` in order to build all my dependencies of my library classes. I've been struggling to solve a trouble for a week and I'm really exhausted. I need some help.

This is my class:

```
class Core : ICoreService, ICore {
    private ICoreConfiguration configuration;

    Core(ICoreconfiguration configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    override ICoreService.ParentMethod() {   //ICoreService implementation
        foreach (Item item in this.configuration.Items)
            this.ChildMethod();
    }
    virtual ChildMethod() {
      //do something
    }
}
```

`ICoreService` is:

```
interface ICoreService {
    void ParentMethod();
}
```

`ICore` is:

```
interface ICore {
    ICoreConfiguration Configuration { get; }
}
```

`ICoreConfiguration` is:

```
interface ICoreConfiguration {
    IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; }
}
```

My test is:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UsersManagementTests
{
    private readonly NSubstituteMockingKernel IoCKernel;

    public UsersManagementTests()
    {
        this.IoCKernel = new NSubstituteMockingKernel();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.IoCKernel.Reset();
    }

    [Test(Description = "Configured Users are well loaded on Kernel")]
    public void InitializationWithUsersTest()
    {
        //Setup Data
        Item item = Item.Create("item1");
        IEnumerable<Item> items = new List<Item>() { item };

        //Setup Mocks
        this.IoCKernel
            .Get<ICoreConfiguration>()
            .Items
                .Returns(items);
        Core core = this.IoCKernel.Get<Core>();

        //Act
        kernel.ParentMethod();

        //Assert
        IEnumerable<NSubstitute.Core.ICall> calls = kernel.ReceivedCalls(); // ((((((1))))))
        kernel.Received(1).ChildMethod();                                                    // ((((((2))))))
    }
}
```

When `((((((1))))))` or `((((((2))))))` are reached, I'm getting this `NSubstitute.Exceptions.NotASubstituteException` exception message now on last line:

> NSubstitute extension methods like .Received() can only be called on objects created using Substitute.For() and related methods.

As you can see I'm trying to test `ChildMethod` method is reached once at least. `ChildMethod` must be called according to my `Core.Kernel` implementation.

I will really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are struggling with using the mocking kernel is it possible to strip your tests back to basics and manually create the classes involved? You can even create substitutes by hand (manually implement the dependency interfaces/override classes) to eliminate any complexity NSubstitute adds. Not sure if this is doable in your case, but thought I'd mention it as I've found this approach very useful for getting un-stuck.

Comment: I can't help you with the mocking kernel stuff sorry, but this exception means the `kernel` object was not created via `Substitute.For<yourtype>` so no NSubstitute calls will work with it. I can't see where `kernel` is new'd up, but if you're pulling it out of the container it looks like it is pulling the concrete type rather than a substitute.

Comment: Yes, I really thought that. If I'm getting an object from an `NSubstituteMockingKernel` why this object isn't a mock (substitution). The documentation is absolutly bad, and I'm thinking it doesn't work.

Comment: I honestly don't see any value in this `mocking kernel`. This is simply realizable via reflection (as i've done numerous times) - inspect constructor for the class under test and for each parameter call Substute.For<>